# Same piped call to isql works on Solaris but not on RHEL

Tags: solaris, ksh, rhel, isql

**Background:**  I need to port a `ksh` script from SunOS 5.10 to RHEL 5.8.  It makes a call to isql to retrieve some data and, quite contrary to the intended application of final endpoint client utilities such as isql, it parses its out to be used by a variable in the shell script.  Please note that I just inherited this and by no means did design such a hack myself.  I certainly never would be parsing isql out to assign value to a var in shell -- if the script needed that info, I would use Perl with some API like DBD::DBI that is designed to marshall data between the application and the data store.  But I have what I have and must work within the parameters.

What is happening is that the following piped input does return data on SunOS but not in RHEL:

```
echo "SELECT some_field FROM some_table WHERE some_crtra = 'X' \ngo" | isql -U$USER -P$PASS -D$DB -S$SERVER
```

That output on Solaris being:

```
 some_field 
 ------
 Y

(1 row affected)
```

From that point, the script uses `awk` to extract just the field value from the above stream but let's ignore that because that's not the problem.

Also please note that I am able to get the data executing the piped commands separately, i.e. by going manually into isql and running the SQL.  So the SQL or the connection string are not the problem -- it is either how the piping streams data OR isql itself works differently on the different platforms.

Can anybody see why there is disparate response to the same input on the two systems?  Any idea how I can change the piping to make it work?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo "SELECT some_field FROM some_table WHERE some_crtra = 'X' \ngo"
```

is non portable.

I would suggest instead:

```
printf "SELECT some_field FROM some_table WHERE some_crtra = 'X' \ngo\n"
```

From the ksh93 manual page:

When  the  first  arg  does  not begin with a -, and none of the
arguments contain a \, then echo prints each  of  its  arguments
separated  by  a space and terminated by a new-line.  **Otherwise,
the behavior of echo is system dependent  and  print  or  printf
described  below  should  be  used.** See  echo(1) for usage and
description.

Comment: that did it.  do you have any idea if the non-portability is due to the versions of UNIX or Sybase?

Comment: That's a shell issue. Historically, echo had two incompatible implementations and the behavior of this builtin command is system dependant. printf was created to provide a portable way to handle control characters . Answer updated.

Comment: closing the chapter on this fix sure comes pretty sweet to start the weekend...  many thanks to you sir